# Why does the U.S. seek to establish a demilitarized Palestinian state?

Tags: united-states, israel, palestine, foreign-policy, hamas

[Recently](https://www.axios.com/2024/01/31/palestine-statehood-biden-israel-gaza-war), Secretary of State Antony Blinken asked the State Department to conduct a review and present policy options on possible U.S. and international recognition of a Palestinian state after the war in Gaza but there seems to be a requirement that it is to be demilitarized.

This can easily be seen as a reason to ensure the security of Israel and prevent launch of missiles by Hamas or other similar Palestinian factions with military wings, but if Hamas and other such factions currently only seek the establishment of an independent state with recognized sovereignty, and added the fact that Israel has a robust air-defense system:

Why does the U.S. believe that Palestine needs to be demilitarized?

Comment: I voted to reopen because this question can be and has been answered well by a frame challenge (kind of)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> if Hamas and other such factions only seek the establishment of an independent state with recognized sovereignty

That's the thing: *is* that all they seek? [Hamas' 1988 charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Hamas_charter) explicitly called for the destruction of Israel and its subsumption into Palestine. While its [current charter created in 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Hamas_charter) accepts the idea of a Palestinian state within the current 1967 borders, it's widely believed, especially within Israel and its allies, that Hamas still implicitly seeks Israel's destruction. So from their point of view, granting Palestine statehood isn't guaranteed to stop the attacks against Israel - especially if Hamas were to remain in charge of the Gaza Strip - hence the calls for demilitarization.

> and added the fact that Israel has a robust air-defense system

The operative word there being **air** defence. Hamas doesn't *need* missiles to cause mass Israeli casualties, as they demonstrated on October 7th.

Comment: This is a misreading of the 2017 policy document (not a revision of the 1988 charter), which says only that if other Palestinian factions establish a state with all preconditions met (1949 armistice lines, Jerusalem as capital, right of return etc.) Hamas won't throw the members of other factions off rooftops. But Hamas still reserves the "right" to use any & all means, including - & especially - armed resistance.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Israel has [repeatedly](https://www.aljazeera.com/features/2024/1/22/how-israel-has-repeatedly-rejected-hamas-truce-offers) rejected Hamas' truce offers in the past. I don't disagree that Hamas is a radical organization which would probably prefer to liberate all of Palestine if it could (just like Likud on the other side) but this caricature that they're purely irrational Jew-hating genocidal maniacs is just incorrect. There's clearly a push within the movement to moderate itself and this is reflected by the 2017 charter, however imperfect you claim it may be.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 There's no probably about liberating all of Palestine; the 2017 charter is incredibly clear about it.

Comment: @prosfilaes The updated charter talks about accepting the 1967 borders. Yes, they also talk about liberating all of Palestine and not accepting Israel. It's contradictory. It's not clear. It's reflective of an internal debate within the organization. Sort of like how there's an internal debate in the Republican party about e.g., protectionism.

Comment: There's no contradiction; where the 2017 Hamas charter mentions accepting the 1967 borders is in paragraph #20, where it explicitly mentions that as a stopgap solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151312/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-stop-gaza-genocide).

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the (generally excellent) existing answer, from a purely military professional point of view, "having air defense system" isn't a solution. It's a part of a part of a solution which isn't reliable.

- Air defense systems are generally **area** ADS. In other words, they can defend VERY specific small territory, not an entire country. I don't have a serious professional reference at hand, but "Habitual Linecrosser" youtube channel, if you wade through funny airplane voices short videos, has a couple of extremely detailed professional info videos on this topic, the channel owner being a long time missile air defense specialist in US Army.
- Air defense systems aren't infallible **as shown in practice**. In case you missed it, Israel WAS hit by missiles, repeatedly, including with casualties, both in the current war of Oct 7th, as well as earlier numerous attacks by Palestinians.
- Air defense systems aren't infallible even in theory. They can break, they can make mistakes (hardware AND software AND wetware do fail). They can be swamped with number of missiles higher than they can handle (which is what Hamas does). They can be tricked with electronic warfare countermeasures. They can be attacked to take them out (what USA did to Iraq in operation "Desert Storm" in 1991). HARM missiles are a "*thing*", and air defense systems rely on radars.
- (non-laser) Air defense systems are extremely expensive. An interceptor costs a ton of money. Keeping the system online and operational costs money.
- And as others said, it's not like missiles are the only attack modality.

Also, leaving aside all those "air defense" considerations above, the point the question is trying to make is ethically akin to "why should we forbid criminals to carry guns and shoot people? People have good bullet proof vests they can carry". No, the **problem is the criminal who wants to shoot people**, not the fact that people need the vest; and the proper solution is to put criminals in jail and not allow criminals to be armed.

Answer (score -3):

This is likely due to political posturing and the US government caving in to [lobbying groups](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2022/may/17/pro-israel-lobby-defeat-democrats-palestinians-2022). If it was genuinely because the US leadership feared that a militarized Palestine would use the weapons to attack Israel, then why does the US fund Israel to the tune of [$3.8 billion a year](https://www.bbc.com/news/57170576) despite widespread evidence of [Israeli atrocities against the Palestinian people](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2023/10/damning-evidence-of-war-crimes-as-israeli-attacks-wipe-out-entire-families-in-gaza/)?

If the argument is that Hamas seeks to wipeout Israel and hence any Palestinian state needs to be demilitarized, then equally Israeli leaders have been [openly calling for all Palestinian lands to be incorporated into Israel](https://www.commondreams.org/news/netanyahu-map). The Israeli deputy foreign minister, on it being put to her that the West Bank is occupied, [responded](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/israel-deputy-foreign-minister-palestinians-occupation-settlements-judea-samaria-tzipi-hotovely-a8033611.html):

> I deny the idea of occupation. This is Judea and Samaria

And:

> When Mr Robinson pointed out that the UN and many governments
> recognise the West Bank as occupied by Israel, Ms Hotovely said Israel
> could not "be an occupier in a land that the Jewish people belonged to
> for thousands of years."

Thus, there is no rational reason for the US to demand a demilitarized Palestine whilst actively arming Israel.